# How can I get OS default apps in android

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'm developing a launcher app, I need to retrieve an Android OS default Phone app, Browser app and SMS apps', application Info (Application name, Package name, Launcher icon). Following code is used to get all launchable applications.

```
private static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApps(Context context, PackageManager pm) {
    List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
    List<ApplicationInfo> laughableInstalledApps = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0; i<installedApps.size(); i++){
        if(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(installedApps.get(i).packageName) != null){
            laughableInstalledApps.add(installedApps.get(i));
        }
    }
    return laughableInstalledApps;
}
```

Comment: @nishon.tan my question is not to get list of ALL apps (including System Apps)?

Comment: aa ! I misread the question. I have deleted my comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time with the code, I found a way get what I wanted.

**Default Dial App**

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
ActivityInfo info = pkgAppsList.get(0).activityInfo;
```

**Default SMS App**

```
String smsPkgName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(smsPkgName, 0);
```

**Default Browser App**

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://"));
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(browserIntent, 
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
ActivityInfo info = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [PackageManager#getPreferredActivities(java.util.List, java.util.List, java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html), where the first parameter is a list of `IntentFilter`, which you would like to get default apps for. Then the answer is written in list passed as second parameter.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html) are some common intents for which you might try to find default apps.

Comment: Thank you for your tips.